# Unblur pdf document

Tags: pdf, text-processing

I've a pdf document and some pages are blurred (see figure below please). I tried to unblur it by using ScanWritr and AvePDF, but without any success.

Could you suggest me a tool to do that please?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get teh document?  Is it supposed to be protected?

Comment: @RohitGupta I've a pdf given to me by a friend; he downloaded it long time ago so he doesn't remember the source.

Comment: Two things come to mind.  Either its some sort of protection because you are not authorised to look at it.  Or, you are missing a font that it is using.