# Blur pdf document

Tags: pdf, text-processing, documentation-generator

I am looking for a tool to blur a pdf document like below; so far I found only online and offline tools to black out text (e.g. Adobe, smallpdf, redactpdf, pdffiller etc.).

[image]

Comment: It might help to know what you are trying to do.  You are asking the opposite in [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/88772/unblur-pdf-document)

Comment: RohitGupta this question is just a curiosity.